# Regex replacement in strings

Tags: c#, regex

I have string pairs as :

```
s_1 : "He graduated in 1994 with 32 courses" 
s_2 : "I graduated in 0000 with 00 courses"
```

What I want to do is modify `s_2`, such that `0000` gets changed to `1994` and `00` to 32.

```
modified_s_2 : "I graduated in 1994 with 32 courses"
```

Basically, `0000...n_times...0` tells about that it's going to be matched with string number with `n` digits in `s_1`.

I can implement this by looping. 
I am looking for efficient implementation. I think regex implementation would be easy for this.

Note : There can any `n` numbers in strings, and each number can have any number of digits.

Comment: Using a loop or regex to find the n-digit strings in `s_1` is the hard-part. Don't use regex for the replacement - that should be simple.

Comment: So s2 is basically some "pseudo regex" that should match s1 and then replace the correspondign values?

Comment: @CSharpie s2 u can consider s2 to be a random string which has digits as "00000...0". We just want to replace this series of 0 , with some number in s1 which has same number of digits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you mean this:

```
var s_1 = "He graduated in 1994 with 32 courses";
var s_2 = "I graduated in 0000 with 00 courses 0000";

//// I'll find combination of '0's to be replaced
var regexes =
    Regex.Matches(s_2, @"\b0+\b")
        .OfType<Match>()
        .Select(c => new { c.Value, Reg = new Regex(c.Value.Replace("0", @"\d")) })
        .ToList();

//// now I replace each '0's combination with first match 
var curS1 = s_1;
foreach (var regex in regexes)
{
    var s1Value = regex.Reg.Match(curS1).Value;
    curS1 = regex.Reg.Replace(curS1, "", 1);     //// I remove first match of s_1 to don't matched again
    s_2 = new Regex(regex.Value).Replace(s_2, s1Value, 1);
}
```

[**[ C# Demo ]**](http://rextester.com/QOXDUB98438)

A test cases can be:

```
var s_1 = "He graduated in 1994 with 32 courses then 254 for 1998";
var s_2 = "I graduated in 0000 with 00 courses then 000 for 0000";
```

That result will be:

```
I graduated in 1994 with 32 courses then 254 for 1998
```

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this can get you started since you're looking for regex. You can modify it to be in a loop for whatever kind of "string pairs" you are using.

This is how the regex looks visually: [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/cZGEzz/3) (this is why we do the `.Trim()` below). I changed it so it's less tied to that specific example and can work with a variety of numbers in different places

```
var s_1 = "He graduated number 1 in class in 1900 with 20 courses over the course of 12 weeks";
var s_2 = "I graduated number 0 in class in 0000 with 00 courses over the course of 00 weeks";

// Finds the matches in s_1 with the year and the number of courses
// The spaces are important in the regex so we match properly
var regex = new Regex("( \\d{1,} )");
var matches = regex.Matches(s_1);

var lastIndex = 0; // This is necessary so we aren't replacing previously replaced values
foreach(var match in matches.Cast<Match>())
{
    // The matched value, removing extra spaces
    var trimmedMatch = match.Value.Trim();

    // The n-length 0 string in s_2
    var zeroString = new String('0', trimmedMatch.Length);

    // A simpler way to replace a string within a string
    var sb = new StringBuilder(s_2);
    var replaceIndex = s_2.IndexOf(zeroString, lastIndex);
    sb.Remove(replaceIndex, zeroString.Length);
    sb.Insert(replaceIndex, trimmedMatch);

    s_2 = sb.ToString();

    // This is necessary otherwise we could end up overwriting previously done work
    lastIndex = replaceIndex + zeroString.Length;
}
```

Comment: U are solving just for this case. The # of digits can be variable. And even the # of numbers present in string can be variable

Comment: Ah I think I misunderstood your problem.

Comment: Looking at shA.t's solution seems more concise. I don't know which is more efficient though. Implement them both and run some tests to see which runs faster and that should be your answer. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Disclamer: I let you handle the error of if the patern string `"00"` is not in the string.

As I don't have information about the real performance issue that you encounter in your implementation but you can count the number of digit in each your input and templated output so you know if they match.

```
string input = "He graduated in 1994 with 32 coursesHe graduated in 1994 with 32 coursesHe graduated in 1994 with 32 courses ";            
string ouput = "He 0000 with 00 He in 0000 with 00 He in 0000 with 00";
string regex = @"(\d+)";

var matches = Regex.Matches(input, regex).Cast<Match>();
var tempSB = new StringBuilder(ouput);
foreach(var i in matches)
{
    var strI = i.Value;
    var strILength = strI.Length;

    var template = new string('0', strILength );
    var index = ouput.IndexOf(template);    // if (index ==-1) exception;

    tempSB.Remove(index, strILength);
    tempSB.Insert(index, strI);

    ouput = tempSB.ToString();
}
```

For a 50Mo input it take about 10 sec. Thats sound reasonable.